# Python3.6, ftp_tls and session reuse

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftplib, session-reuse

So, I'm struggling trying to upload a file to a remote ftps server that requires session reuse.

I must specify that even if I can connect to the server without problems via Filezilla, I get the error "unknown server certificate".

This is my script:

```
import ftplib
import ssl

USER = "username"
PASS = "password"
SERVER = "1.2.3.4"
PORT = 21
BINARY_STORE = True

filepath = '/path/to/myfile.txt'
filename = 'myfile.txt'

content = open(filepath, 'rb')
ftp = ftplib.FTP_TLS()
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
print (ftp.connect(SERVER, PORT))
print (ftp.login(USER, PASS))
print (ftp.prot_p())
print (ftp.set_pasv(True))

print (ftp.cwd("testfolder"))
print (ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % filename, content))
ftp.quit()
```

But I get this message: **450 TLS session of data connection has not resumed or the session does not match the control connection**

The file is created on server but it's empty (0 bytes size)
I've read dozen posts and I clearly understood that I must implement session reuse on client side too - which is supported from Python 3.6 - but simply... I don't know how to do this, since I can't find any working example.

Someone suggested to extend FTP_TLS class:

```
class MyFTP_TLS(ftplib.FTP_TLS):
    """Explicit FTPS, with shared TLS session"""
    def ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest=None):
        conn, size = ftplib.FTP.ntransfercmd(self, cmd, rest)
        if self._prot_p:
            session = self.sock.session
            if isinstance(self.sock, ssl.SSLSocket):
                    session = self.sock.session
            conn = self.context.wrap_socket(conn,
                                            server_hostname=self.host,
                                            session=session)  # this is the fix
        return conn, size
ftp = MyFTP_TLS()
...
```

But now the server response is: **'SSLSocket' object has no attribute 'session'**

So I'm stuck. What am I missing?

Comment: OK! My fault! A silly fault indeed...
The default Python3 running version on my system was 5.3.5, so using Python3.6 - and extenting FTP_TLS library as in my example) works like a charm!

Comment: I had the same issue using python 3.7.1. When I extended the FTP_TLS library as described, I got an exception, but surprisingly the file was uploaded successfully.

Comment: Solution also worked for me in Python 3.7. Code run without hitting any exception.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you?

```
from ftplib import FTP_TLS

USER = "username"
PASS = "password"
SERVER = "1.2.3.4"
PORT = 21 

ftps = FTP_TLS(SERVER)
ftps.login(USER, PASS)         
ftps.prot_p()         
ftps.set_pasv(True)
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify that I connect correctly.
The error message is raised when I try to transfer the file:
ftp.storbinary('STOR %s' % filename, content)